# Handling WCF errors

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I have a desktop c# app that uploads a stream of images to my server using WCF.

For testing I wanted to simulate handling errors when my server is down.

When I looked on MSDN it told me to use the `Abort` method, which I implemented.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(package);
}
catch (TimeoutException tex)
{
    wcf.Abort();
    //log error
}
catch (ServiceActivationException sae)
{
    wcf.Abort();
    //log error
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    wcf.Abort();
    ErrorLogger.AddError("Engine", "ProcessFrame.3", new Exception("Service Communication Error"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    wcf.Abort();
    //log error
}
```

So, to test this I run my client app. I went to my server and stopped IIS. I waited a few seconds and restarted IIS.

The streaming did not resume.

I am guessing that after I used `Abort()` I would need to reconnect my client?

If so then that would be impractical for my application.

Is there a better way of dealing with server/internet issues in terms of 'tidying up' after an error has been thrown?

Thanks

Comment: So, are you asking about how to set up an automatic reconnection?

Comment: @EngineerSpock Hi, sorry for the delay in my response,  To answer: no I am not. This is because if i remove the abort methods. Then re-test doing teh same thing then my 'feed' resumes. I just wanted to know should I be disposing of anything related to my call?

Comment: Well, generally speaking you MUST invoke abort. In the other case you can face unpredictable results, including memory leaks.

Comment: Well, I have never done so.  The app has been running on 3 PCs 24/7 for just over 3 months and has never caused a problem. I was just reviewing my code to see if I can improve it. Why would I face an unpredictable result? The endpoint is connected to once only and I just invoke the method from my code. But thanks for taking your time comment. It IS appreciated.. :)

Comment: As I recall, there is no need to catch Exception. In the worst case the type of the exception will be of CommunicationException type. You don't need to dispose anything related to you calls made on created channel. However, of course, you still need to dispose all objects which hold some unmanaged objects. All rules are still the same)))

Comment: Hi, that was what I thought too.  I just wanted to check if that was the case with my peers here.  Just 1 thing based on what you just stated.. you said do NOT catch the Exception. The Exception is raised though so it needs to be caught somewhere?

Comment: Hmmm, feels strange for me, because I thought, that WCF calls never raise Exceptions of the most general type (Exception). I thought that they will be presented as FaultException or CommunicationException.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Apologies.  You meant just remove the Exception catch. I will do. See? i have improved my code - many thanks

Comment: I was wrong. Don't do that. Just check what I said, but it seems I was wrong. However, it is very bad when such an exception raises from the server. Exception have to be created as Faults in WCF. And don't forget that one-ways operations can't raise any exceptions at all.

Comment: lol. OK, I was going to test anyway. But thanks for correcting yourself